# Location bar for pop up window is not common for all browsers. How can we make it common across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

Am opening a popup window using the below code. To be specific, It pops up a calendar widget.

```
window.open("", "xyz", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
```

The problem is :

The popup window location bar(url) is different across all browsers:

IE  : No Address bar.

Mozilla  : Address bar same as parent window.

Chrome : Address bar as "about:blank"

I have to make this common across all browsers. Is there any way to set the address bar?

Can anyone please explain me?

Comment: You can't reliably force browsers to hide UI elements. Browsers have a bunch of settings that can force specific elements to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus. My intent is not to hide the elements. I want to make it common across all browsers.

Comment: The only way to make it consistent across browsers, reliably, is to just set it to display it all.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there any approach to make it consistent?

Comment: @Cerebrus has it right. Every browser has specific things you can or cannot do to pop-up windows. THe best thing you can do for your calendar pop-up is to add it into the page instead, so you can ensure a cross browser common UI.